# How to compute proportion of a particular field in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have a SQL table `data`  as

```
ID       Date   Action    Params
 A   20151001      Foo         1
 A   20151002      Foo         2
 A   20151001      Bar        10
 B   20151001      Foo         0
 B   20151002      Foo         0
 B   20151003      Bar         1
```

In a single query, given a particular ID, I want to compute the proportion of entries that has action `Foo`. For example, given A, there are 2 `Foo`s out of 3 actions. So it'd be 66%.

I want something like this

```
SELECT SUM(IF action = 'Foo', 1, 0)*100 / count(*)
FROM data
WHERE ID='A'
```

But `IF` doesn't work in postgres. Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: `SUM()` works.  Your problem is the `IF`.

Comment: thanks for catching this. i've edited the original post

Answer (score 3):

```
select id, count(action = 'Foo' or null) * 100.0 / count(*)
from data
group by id
```

Comment: why you have to add `or null` ?

Comment: Because it is `count()` not `sum()`. `Count()` counts `not null` values.

Comment: This is my favorite. Even! better than mine ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use a `CASE` instead of `IF`

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/93a09/9)

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
               WHEN "Action" = 'Foo' THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
            END)*100 / count(*)
FROM data
WHERE "ID"='A'
group by "ID"
```

Just aditional bonus you may want use analytic functions

```
SELECT 
      "ID",
      "Action",
      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY "ID", "Action" ORDER BY "ID") as aTotal,
      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY "ID" ORDER BY "ID") as bTotal
From data;
```

Comment: fyi. I include an easy way of calculate all the  groups at once in my demo.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred way is to just use `avg()`:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN action = 'Foo' THEN 100.0 ELSE 0.0 END)
FROM data
WHERE ID = 'A';
```

You can also use `GROUP BY` to get this for all ids:

```
SELECT ID, AVG(CASE WHEN action = 'Foo' THEN 100.0 ELSE 0.0 END)
FROM data
GROUP BY ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Case` is unnecessary:

```
select sum((action = 'Foo')::int)* 100/ count(*)
from data
where id = 'A'
```